# My neighbours iphone paired with my PC via bluetooth without me knowing

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I discovered my neighbours iphone had some how become paired with my computer without me knowing. I know it was my neighbour because it's pretty obvious from the device name.

I check var/log/syslog and it looks like the connection was somehow established yesterday evening. I know for sure I wasn't messing around with bluetooth settings or devices yesterday  so I doubt I accidentally accepted a pairing request.

Any ideas how this happened?

Comment: switch off bluetooth ... or blacklist the spying urls in your firewall-settings (iptables).